# How to solve these simultaneous equations:

Tags: mathematical-modeling

$1 = 1/2y - bx,$
$1 = 1/2x - ay$

I need x,y it in terms of constants, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Do you mean $(1/2)y$ or $1/(2y)$ (similar question for $1/2x$)?

Answer (score 0):

From the 1st equation, 
$2+2bx = y$
Putting in the 2nd,
$$1 = \frac12x - 2a-2abx\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{1+2a}{1/2-2ab}$$
if $ab\neq \frac14$. We also have 
$$y=2+\frac{1+2a}{1-4ab}$$
If $ab=\frac{1}{4}$,
$$1 = \frac12x - 2a-2x=-\frac{1}{2}$$
which is impossible